# Android Vertical Textview Marquee Widget

Tags: android, widget, textview

I want to know if it's possible to create TextView marque verticaly in Android widget. i already try with horizontal but i want my textview marquee by verticaly.

Already googling for several hour but not find something usefull i can use..
Any suggestion ?

Comment: did you find any solution for this? kindly share if you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-->

Add these tags inside your `<TextView>`

```
android:ems = "1" 
android:multipleLine = true
```